# Обновить Last_insert_id() если уже есть поле

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно проверить есть ли в таблице поле с заданной датой,если нет,то создать, если есть - положить в last_insert_id() id существующего поля. Пытался сделать так,но что-то не получается

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO current_schedule (id_schedule, date) VALUES ('{}','{}') \
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id);".format(id_schedule,lessondate))
```

Дело в том,что после этого мне нужно добавлять записи в соответствии c полученным id.

```
if flag == str_to_bool('true'):
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO statistic (id_student, id_current_schedule,here) \
                    VALUES ('{}',LAST_INSERT_ID(),1)".format(id_student))
    if flag == str_to_bool('false'):
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO statistic (id_student, id_current_schedule,here) \
                    VALUES ('{}',LAST_INSERT_ID(),0)".format(id_student))
```

В моем случае запись добавляется каждый раз с новым id, возможно неправильный подход вовсе?

Comment: last_insert_id содержит id последней _вставленной записи_. Если вставка не происходит (хотя бы потому, что запись уже есть) то этой функцией пользоваться нельзя. И менять id существующей записи так же не стоит. P.S. и вставлять и получать id можно только записей, у _поля_ не может быть id и "вставить поле" невозможно, потому что это часть записи

Comment: @Mike то есть,как-то "просто" тут разобраться не получится # cursor.execute("INSERT INTO current_schedule (id_schedule, date) \
    # SELECT * FROM (SELECT '{}','{}') AS tmp \
    # WHERE NOT EXISTS ( \
    # SELECT date  FROM current_schedule WHERE date = '{}' \
    # ) LIMIT 1;".format(id_schedule,date,lessondate))  .Так и далее через if уже те запросы выполнять?

Comment: Я не знаю получится или нет, потому что из вашего вопроса совершенно не ясно, чего вы пытаетесь достичь. Возможно вам просто стоит после вставки воспользоваться select, что бы получить id записи, вне зависимости от того была она до этого или только что добавлена. И при необходимости select можно использовать непосредственно в insert в виде `insert into .... select ...`